# Dev Console Query Error - SObject Type Is Not Supported

Tags: developer-console

Why I'm getting the error regardless whether I execute standard or custom objects I'm getting error

> sObject type `work_order__c` is not supported.

```
//custom object
Select status__c from work_order__c

//standard object
Select Phone from Contact
```

> sObject type `Contact` is not supported.

here is the screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Please uncheck `Use Tooling  API` checkbox and try.
Use tooling API checkbox is **available on developer console** -> query editor -> execute button -> use tooling API.

Comment: silly me arggg...